# Documentation protocol DAAP apple

Tags: ios, itunes, daap

does someone know about documentation of this protocol? I need it in my app to communicate with Itunes.

Thanks advanced!

Comment: Have you tried googling?

Comment: yes, i had found nothing about protocol

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge Apple has never published any kind of specification for DAAP.  You can find a reasonable reverse engineering effort [here](http://www.opendaap.org/)